# Leg glitching after adding IK constraint

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, eevee-render-engine, inverse-kinematics

I figured out the problem to my last question with the help of someone else and I successfully changed the bones from FK to IK. But now that it’s working, the leg glitches at some parts when I imported a motion. It works just fine when I move it in pose mode have linked pictures below and a blend file, and I’d also like to point out that I am on blender 2.8 using the render engine eevee. Thank you in advance.

How it’s supposed to look (yes I am using the same model again because she is the only one out of all the other models this person made that works well):

[image]

What it looks like:

[image]

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzMOVdW7vfMENaA4cqfwf81jjeMmAke1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are there any constraints on the armature(rotation etc)?...they normally cause such kind of glitching

Comment: @starzar How would I check that?

Comment: @starzar Oh, like limit rotation? Then yes, I do because it needs it. If I remove it, then it's even worse than before, + it does not fix the glitching unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints on the armature(rotation etc) normally cause such kind of glitching.

The effect of the constraints can be limited by ***setting the minimum and the maximum values .***

[image]

Comment: I actually think I am getting closer thanks to you, I'm looking at a model that works and what numbers she put in and I tried those but it unfortunately didn't work, so right now I'm kinda testing all the numbers. Do you have any recommendations? I am only using limit X.

Comment: First disable the constraint (eye icon) to confirm if it because of the constraint and if so ,only then tweak the values.

Comment: Alright, it is the issue. Sorry one last thing, would this fully remove the glitching or just minimize it?

Comment: Glitching is caused because of the constraint values set ...they have to be tweaked (min/max)depending on the model to completly remove it .Check which axis is causing the glitch and then tweak only those values.

Answer (score 0):

Select you Armature, then In the *Object Data* properties, change the method of *IK Solver* from *Standard* to *iTaSC*.

[image]

[image]